# Assign the contents of a blob field to combobox items

Tags: delphi, string, blob

I have list of country names or other strings in a text blob field. When I read the field, I get a string back with `LfCr` between the words or phrases. Is there an easy way to assign this string to the `Items` property of a `TComboBox`? I'm using `TADOQuery` on a `FireBird 2.1` Database.

Regards, Pieter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got LFCRs between the phrases, then just assign the string to the `Items.Text` property, which takes a string and splits it into individual items at the linebreaks.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. (I could not accept the answer as I have to wait at lease 8 minutes it seems!!)

Comment: Another option is to read the blob as a TStream using the TDataSet.CreateBlobStream() method, and then call the Items.LoadFromStream() method.